# Clarity Smart contract validate principal calling public function

Tags: stack, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

When writing a Clarity Smart contract, how can you validate the principal that is calling into a public function.

I don't know where to find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

`tx-sender` contains the principal that sent the transaction. It can be used to validate the principal that is calling into a public function.

You can also use `contract-caller` which works a bit differently. If this is the first contract called by the transaction signer, it will be the same as `tx-sender`. If `contract-call?` was used to call into another contract, it will return the calling contract.

https://docs.stacks.co/docs/clarity/language-keywords#contract-caller